# Linked Library Add-on: Cannot return to original file

Tags: add-on, linked-data, library, library-overrides

I have linked a collection of a blend file in another blend file (Main Comp). I have activated the "Linked Library Add-on" in Preferences. I can switch from the Main Comp to the linked blend file via the button "Edit Library: Collection". This works without any problems. But strangely I can't get back from there. In the add-on the option "Return to Original File" is not offered. Did I miss something? Thanks for your help!

[image: Screenshot]

[ToggleSystemConsole](https://we.tl/t-ehfhejM92W)

```
-----------------
Read prefs: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\config\userpref.blend
cmolcore imported with success! v1.12
Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\ST_Roh\ST_Roh11.blend
Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"
Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\ST_Roh\..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Info: Saved "Blaetter.blend"

Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\ST_Roh\ST_Roh11.blend
Info: Read library:  'F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', '//..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', parent '<direct>'
Info: Read library:  'F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', '//..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', parent '<direct>'

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"
Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\ST_Roh\..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Info: Saved "Blaetter.blend"

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
Info: Saved "Blaetter.blend"

Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\ST_Roh\ST_Roh11.blend
Info: Read library:  'F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', '//..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', parent '<direct>'
Info: Read library:  'F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', '//..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend', parent '<direct>'

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"

Info: Saved "ST_Roh11.blend"
Read blend: F:\Unsere_Daten_Chri\Kreation\Bundesforste\Sieben Thesen\Filme\ST_Blender\ST_Roh\..\Material\Links\Blaetter+Sockel\Blaetter.blend
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\object_edit_linked.py", line 183, in draw
    icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: This looks like something bugged out. Could you go to Window > toggle System Console and copy paste errors in your question (if any) ?

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you for the hint! I edited the question and put a link to the text document! Cheers

Comment: Erm sorry but I'm not so keen on downloading a random txt file from the internet ^^ could you just copy/paste the contents into you question ?

Comment: @Gorgious  yeah, you're right. I pasted it in the question!

Comment: This is a far cry but try to unhide the light object and then select it in the viewport ?

Comment: Or select any other object for that matter

Comment: @Gorgious Man, that really solved the issue. I have no idea why but that was it! Does the add-on only work with lights turned on?! Can I give you a check mark or something for that? Sry Im fairly new here.

Comment: You're doing great don't worry :) I added my answer below, you can tick the checkmark in the top left if you want to express gratitude for solving your problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error that's being repetitively printed out in the system console :

```
icon = "OUTLINER_DATA_" + context.active_object.type.replace("LIGHT_PROBE", "LIGHTPROBE")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

The add-on functionality assumes that you have an active object in the code, apparently in order to draw something in the panel interface. Normally the developper would safeguard the code so this doesn't happen, but this edge case hasn't been taken into consideration.

You would need to select an object in the interface so `context.active_object` doesn't return a non existant object and the interface draws correctly.